# How to escape percent sign inside table?

Tags: symbols

The problem is that I have code fragment looking like this:

`\detokenize{Some Funky Stuff 20%}`

And texlive is saying that `! File ended while scanning use of \tabu@collectbody.`. If I remove the % sign, the error goes away, but this sign has to be present there. If I however escape the % sign with a backslash \, then PDF is being generated, but with a backslash visible - in other words I see `\%` in PDF. How to do it the right way?

EDIT:

Didn't know it's important, but it seems it is - I'm experiencing this problem when working with tables, for example:

```
\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {b{80pt}b{78pt}b{40pt}P{100pt}P{70pt}b{35pt}}
Start & End & Duration & Comment & Category & Lost Prod. {[kWh]} \\  \noalign{\vskip 2pt} \hline 
\endhead
    \noalign{\vskip 4pt} \multicolumn{6}{l}{ \setrow{\bfseries} SOMETHING } \\
        \rowfont{\small\baselineskip=5pt} 2016-09-02 19:20:00 & 2016-09-02 22:50:00 & 03,5:30:00 & {\catcode`\%=12 \detokenize{Some Funky Stuff 20%}} & \detokenize{Utility} & 0 \\
    \noalign{\vskip 2pt} \hline \noalign{\vskip 2pt}
    \rowfont{\small\baselineskip=5pt} \multicolumn{2}{l}{Total for the stuff: } & \multicolumn{3}{l}{24.22:02:33 } & 640239,4 \\
\end{longtabu}
```

Comment: why do you need detokenize here? just `Funky Stuff 20\%` would work, other use cases may need other solutions, `\verb|Funky Stuff 20%|` perhaps  but....

Comment: Because sometimes other characters are appearing - like ampersand for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\detokenize` macro is similar to , but not the same as verbatim.  In particular, braces need to be matched, and `%` are still used to discard the remains of the input record.  One can work around that by redefining `%` to be the same catcode as a numerical digit, within the scope of the `\detokenize`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
{\catcode`\%=12 \detokenize{Some Funky Stuff 20%}}

Here it is a comment again% BLAH
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work :( . I'm using lualatex btw.

Comment: @SzwornyDziąch What doesn't work about it?  Do you mean in the context of your own code, or directly as my small example?  For me, it works both in pdflatex as well as lualatex.

Comment: Please see my edited question. Indeed your solution works in general, but my special case is tables :(

Comment: Ok, I moved `\catcode` couple levels higher - to surround my table and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: @SzwornyDziąch Seeing your `tabu` example, I was going to suggest exactly that... moving the `\catcode` scope around the complete `longtabu`.